# Stretched Image in Container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I upload a file into this container it stretches the image.... how do i get it so it just centres the image but won't stretch it but also the container stays the same size?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="blah2" alt="Your Pixboard Image Here" width="196" height="296" />

<input type="file" 
    onchange="$('#blah2')[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
```

Comment: You are defining height & width which would stretch anything that is not 196 x 296, what happens if you just define one (i.e. only height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `background-position` and `background-cover` property to achieve this

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/frqt6kac/1/)

Your HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="blah2">Your pixelboard image here</div>

<input type="file" 
    onchange="$('#blah2').css('background-image', 'url('+window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])+')')">
```

And CSS

```
#blah2 {
  width:196px; 
  height:296px;
  background-image: url('path/to/image');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define [max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) and [max-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp) for your image and not width and height.
That way your image will be reduced to stay in your box.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the height of the image

`<img id="blah2" alt="Your Pixboard Image Here" width="196" /`>
Check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/frqt6kac/)

Comment: He need his image to stay in the container. With this solution if you got a "tall but slim" image that will destroy the layout.